# how can i get the values that are about to be sent to the database by the TableAdapter through the datagridview?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, dataset, tableadapter

I'm entering sales entries using a TabaleAdapter and a dataGridView. When a row is about to be saved, i want to check the StockBalance of the selected product and verify that current stock for selected product is not less than amount being sold. if its less i want to cancel the sale, so how can get the values that are about to be inserted or updated by the TableAdapter from the example code below?

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowValidated(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

            this.Validate();
            this.itemSalesBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.itemSalesTableAdapter.Update(this.businessDataDataSet);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this command before calling `Update(...)`:

```
DataSet changesDataSet = businessDataDataSet.GetChanges();
```

Now you should have a DataSet object that shows what is going to be transmitted to the database.